# Update a multi dimensional array targeted by path string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional associative array. Input to my program is a string that is compose of keys from the array separated by brackets. How can I target the array and update a value?

**Input**

```php
$array = Array
(
    [store_name] => Jota
    [social] => Array
        (
            [fb] => foo

        )
)

$pattern = "[social][fb];"

$value = "bar";
```

**Desired Output**

```php
$array = Array
(
    [store_name] => Jota
    [social] => Array
        (
            [fb] => bar
        )
)
```

I tried few attempts by using regex & variable reference but nothing is likely to be pasted here. You can say I am unable to think of an Idea to achieve this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to get the keys entered:

```
$pattern = '[social][fb]';
$matched = preg_match_all('/\[([^\[\]]+)\]/', $pattern, $keys);
```

This regex may look messy, but it's not that bad.  It's just checking for any character (that isn't `[` or `]`) that's inside `[]`.

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/Y0bw8f/1

Then you can loop over the found keys until you get to the end and then update the array value.  This can be done by making a reference to the array and then moving it down for each key until you get to the value.

```
if ($matched !== false) {
    $arrayKeys = $keys[1];  // Get the 1st groups from the matched values
    $arrayPointer =& $array;  // Create a reference to the array

    foreach ($arrayKeys as $k) {
        $arrayPointer =& $arrayPointer[$k];  // Move the reference down each key
    }

    $arrayPointer = $value;  // Update the value
    unset($arrayPointer);  // Destroy the reference
}

var_dump($array);
```

Full code demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBBT4QwEIXv/RUjIRbiJhvPiMarXryXSmbZVsgCbUrZZGP87TgUVtfEbC8t7735Hq2t7TQ9PNnashidwxPk8DzvCQNafPDGqbLHTnHIH4G/GI98s3qmarAN@sVIWFzvlrw2hgc5ZWnGWGzRe@V6aonEMi@F3skoY/ER21HNxg5dNGc79FWt9iRZpz7K8Fli2yZ8W4hEvBeikPIuLeSWb@BMptNBnYa5rNGQ/EBu8hw0toNK4TP80HLdV8pSQZgR9zK7sN5M0xMR8ttVIOTsanoRrGpi/xJwIMSZfAWxCiI@rFVf7L9GWB5jiYz9oHzyJ0G3o8EjunI/dnb10myavgE)